# Destructively delete every other element from a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm successfully able to delete every other element from a linked list in a non destructive way (by returning a new linked list). Here's that function:

```
public static Link<Integer> everyOther(Link<Integer> link){
    if(link == null) return null; 
    if(link.next == null) return link;
    return new Link(link.data, everyOther(link.next.next)); 
}
```

For an input list of 1, 2, 3, 4 it successfully returns 1, 3.

However I'm now trying to do this destructively (with void return type) and I'm having trouble. This is my attempt so far:

```
public static void everyOtherDestructive(Link<Integer> link){
    if(link == null) return; 
    if(link.next == null) return;
    if(link.next.next != null){
        link.next = link.next.next;
        everyOtherDestructive(link.next); 

    }               
}
```

This only works for lists of odd lengths but not even. The linked list of 1, 2, 3, 4 should be changed to 1, 3. But instead I'm getting 1, 3, 4.

Can anyone help me understand why it's not skipping over the last element like it should?

Comment: I don't know java, but it seems clear that when it reaches '3' it can't eliminate '4' because the last conditional evaluates as false. To solve the problem, just eliminate that conditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because, when you are at `3`, you do nothing (because `link.next.next` is `null`).

At that point, you should set `link.next` to `null`. This is achieved automatically when you just get rid of the entire if-statement.

```
public static void everyOtherDestructive(Link<Integer> link){
    if(link == null) return; 
    if(link.next == null) return;
    link.next = link.next.next;
    everyOtherDestructive(link.next); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now. For some reason, I wasn't thinking about the fact that there are already base cases testing for null and the extra conditional isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug in your code

After you connect first and third, you go to third and try to get fort and fifth, since fifth is null, you can't get it, but it is ok to set next of third to null, so your last if should be deleted and everything will be fine.

```
public static void everyOtherDestructive(Link<Integer> link){
    if(link == null) return; 
    if(link.next == null) return;
    link.next = link.next.next;  
    everyOtherDestructive(link.next);           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This `if(link.next.next != null)` condition is not required. It skips the last element in even numbered list. Change it as :

```
public void everyOtherDestructive(Link<Integer> link) {
    if (link == null || link.next == null)
        return;
    else {
        link.next = link.next.next;
        everyOtherDestructive(link.next);

    }
}
```